# Slow SSD on Dell 710

Tags: mysql, performance

We recently upgraded our Dell T110 server to a Dell T710 with a 100GB SSD drive.  We were hoping that we would see a tremendous improvement in mysql select performance, but unfortunately the new system is slower than the old.

I have tried tweaking the fstab and the mysql onfiguration, but nothing has seemed to help.  It seems that for some reason the system is unable to use the full speed of the drive or there is something else slowing it down.

According to hdparm the new SSD drive has a similar read speed and surprisingly a slower cached read speed.

When doing a random access data read test using [seeker](http://www.linuxinsight.com/how_fast_is_your_disk.html) the SSD drive is much faster.

Old System:
Dell T110, Single 2.4GHz Quad core processor
8GB of RAM
250 GB 7.2K SATA Drive
Mysql 5.1
ext2 filesystem

Timing buffered disk reads:  100 MB in  0.87 seconds = 114.99 MB/sec
Timing cached reads:   22636 MB in  1.99 seconds = 11361.70 MB/sec
Results: 81 seeks/second, 12.28 ms random access time

New System
Dell T710, Dual 2.13GHz Quad core processor
16 GB of RAM
100 GB SSD Drive
Percona 5.5
ext4 filesystem

Timing buffered disk reads:  366 MB in  3.01 seconds = 121.47 MB/sec
Timing cached reads:   10960 MB in  2.00 seconds = 5487.23 MB/sec
Results: 3742 seeks/second, 0.27 ms random access time

The new system has the following /etc/fstab entry:
/dev/mapper/vg_katahdin-lv_root /                       ext4    defaults,noatime,discard,data=ordered,errors=remount-ro        1 1

Comment: That's completely impossible to answer given the current level of detail. You should check out [ask].

Comment: Yeah - this has no information as to what application you're running, whether your speed issue previously was related to disk I/O, whether the application in question is even capable of making use of multiple cores, etc.

Comment: As others have stated, you've given us no information regarding the performance problem you were and are having and as far as you know it could be anything. Throwing hardware at a performance problem is never the right solution... unless you've diagnosed the problem and know that the replacement hardware will solve it.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback.  I added more detail to the question, which I hope helps.

Comment: At a minimum, compare vmstat between the two machines.  You have a big variable there with Percona, and if I had to guess, you have it tuned very badly.  If you need help ASAP, I'd open a support case with them.  A good DBA will be able to diagnose your OS-level issues as well.  (max processes, open files, etc.)

Answer (score 2):

Before tweaking the disk you should tweak memory usage for the DB - especially with mySQL.

From what I read I suspect that your DB is doing heavy write IO - which is faster on an ext2 and on a "real" disk.

Update 2011-11-23 (after migration to dba):

Perhaps you should analyze your DB with the free TOAD version.

Comment: This is a slave database used for reporting and so it typically does far heavier read operations.

Comment: Is that slave connected or disconnected to the master?

Answer (score 2):

You should add the following to the read slave's /etc/my.cnf and restart mysql

```
[mysqld]
read-only
```

This will prevents users without the SUPER prvilege from performs any updates. Only users with REPLICATION SLAVE and/or SUPER privileges.

If you are running MySQL on Slave Server, you should convert all the tables to MyISAM.

Here is nice script to do so:

```
mysql -u... -p... -AN -e"SELECT CONCAT('ALTER TABLE ',table_schema,'.',table_name,' ENGINE=MyISAM;') InnoDBConversionSQL FROM information_schema.tables WHERE engine='InnoDB' ORDER BY (data_length+index_length)" > ConvertInnoDBToMyISAM.sql
mysql -u... -p... -AN < ConvertInnoDBToMyISAM.sql
```

Answer (score 0):

You must make sure of two things that affect performance:
-parition alignment.
-nature of SSD at intensive write operations: overwriting to non-empty blocks is not possible so the ERASE operation runs on SSD drives to empty unused blocks. It's a very expensive operation which takes few milliseconds. To overcome this challenge, you must use of SSD feature called "reserve space". Set it to about 40% of SSD size then check performance.